# jQuery form validation with checkbox / radio

Tags: html, jquery, css

The code is not working well at all. Where is the problem?

I want the Required Fields to show an error message when I click the Submit button (if there is no value in the checkbox). But if there is a value in the requested field, the error message will be hidden.

It's not working at all. I want to fix this by keeping my HTML structure straight.

```js
$('form.trexcterc').on('submit', function () {

$('.checkbox_required').parent().next('.error').remove(); 
if (!$('.checkbox_required input[required')){

  if (!$('.checkbox_required input:checkbox').is(':checked') || !$('.checkbox_required input:radio').is(':checked')) {
  $(".checkbox_required").parent().after("<span class='error'>error message..</span>");
  } 
}
});
```

```css
.trexcterc {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.form_item label {
  width: 100%;

}

.checkbox_heading {
  margin: 0;
}

.checkbox_item{
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="trexcterc">

<div class="form_item" id="form_item_checkbox" data-type="checkbox-group">

  <!-- Checkbox Group 1 -->
  <label for="after_shot" class="checkbox_heading">After Shot<span class="required_sign">*</span></label>

  <div class="checkbox-group checkbox-inline checkbox_required ">

    <div class="checkbox_item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one" id="checkbox-one" class="" value="Item One" required="required" />              
      <label for="checkbox-one"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-two" id="checkbox-two" class="" value="Item Two" required="required" />              
      <label for="checkbox-two"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-three" id="checkbox-three" class="" value="Item Three" required="required" />              
      <label for="checkbox-three"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Checkbox Group 2 -->
  <div class="checkbox-group checkbox-inline checkbox_required ">

    <label for="after_shot" class="checkbox_heading">Before Shot<span class="required_sign">*</span></label>

    <div class="checkbox_item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-item-one" id="checkbox-item-one" class="" value="Item One" required="required" />              
      <label for="checkbox-one"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-two" id="checkbox-two" class="" value="Item Two" required="required" />              
      <label for="checkbox-two"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Please correct the snippet, there is a js error

Comment: Corrected. please see my update.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is that the native `required` attribute is preventing form submission, so your submit event listener isn't triggered. Instead you can use a simple click event listener.

Another issue is that you need to iterate over each input.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.error').remove();
  $('.checkbox_required input[required]').each((i, el) => {
    if (!el.checked) {
      $(el).closest(".checkbox_item").after("<span class='error'>error message..</span>");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.trexcterc {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.form_item label {
  width: 100%;
}

.checkbox_heading {
  margin: 0;
}

.checkbox_item {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="trexcterc">

  <div class="form_item" id="form_item_checkbox" data-type="checkbox-group">

    <!-- Checkbox Group 1 -->
    <label for="after_shot" class="checkbox_heading">After Shot<span class="required_sign">*</span></label>

    <div class="checkbox-group checkbox-inline checkbox_required ">

      <div class="checkbox_item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one" id="checkbox-one" class="" value="Item One" required="required" />
        <label for="checkbox-one"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox_item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-two" id="checkbox-two" class="" value="Item Two" required="required" />
        <label for="checkbox-two"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox_item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-three" id="checkbox-three" class="" value="Item Three" required="required" />
        <label for="checkbox-three"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Checkbox Group 2 -->
    <div class="checkbox-group checkbox-inline checkbox_required ">

      <label for="after_shot" class="checkbox_heading">Before Shot<span class="required_sign">*</span></label>

      <div class="checkbox_item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-item-one" id="checkbox-item-one" class="" value="Item One" required="required" />
        <label for="checkbox-one"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox_item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-two" id="checkbox-two" class="" value="Item Two" required="required" />
        <label for="checkbox-two"><span class="check_mark"></span>Item One</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

Also note that conditions like this: `if (!$('.checkbox_required input[required'))` doesn't work in jQuery, since selectors always returns a jQuery object. You need to use `.length` to check if element exists. You also have a missing `]` there, it should be
`if (!$('.checkbox_required input[required]').length)`

Comment: Your code is working. Thank you very much. I accepted the answer. But it would be great if you could add another topic here. When I click on the checkbox, the error at the bottom of the check box will be removed. I can't do it at all.